Как перекомпилировать только то, что затронуто моими изменениями?
Есть огромный проект на rust, не меньше 300мб кода (+ wasm и около 400мб ассетов/кмон).
Я начинаю лишь осваиваться и поэтому лезу в боевой код, изменяю что-то по своим хотелкам (в первую очередь пытаюсь что-то изменить в ассетах, но иногда надо надо лезть в сам исходник файлов .rs).
Первый и самый проблемный аспект. Приходится после маленьких правок перекомпилировать проект целиком, что довольно долго. Стараюсь по возможности выносить динамическое и настраиваемое в бд или ассеты, но иногда приходится оставлять это непосредственно в исходнике.
Есть ли по этому поводу подсказки или какие-либо хитрости, чтобы я мог разбить бинарь на составные части, и компилировал только то, что затронуто моими изменениями? Родной компилятор умеет это делать (я не говорю о релизном бинарнике, только дев)? Существуют ли методики или инструменты которые могут помочь организовать правильно этот процесс?

Звучит странно, для dev профиля по умолчанию включена инкрементальная компиляция. Почему это не работает надо разбираться, возможно где-то есть кодогенерация или ещё что-то. Как вариант разбивать проект на отдельные библиотеки и добавить их в один workspace
